# Solve Pythagoras problem solving

Tags: pythagorean-triples

A rectangular piece of paper,10cm by 24cm, is folded so that a pair of diagonally opposite corners coincide. Find the length of the crease.

x^2=(24-x)^2+10^2

Comment: You could try making a paper model of the situation and see if that helps.

Comment: Tried that already

Comment: Is it http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/984115/solving-pythagoras-problem ?

Comment: wat do u mean?    That is the other question i asked earlier but i know how to do it already

Comment: Is there a relationship between the diagonal (determined by the coinciding corners) and the crease line?

Comment: the diagonal length is 26

Comment: Yes, but how is the crease line related to the diagonal line?

Comment: digital brain   does ir7  means x^2=(24-x)^2+10^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : Try To fold Paper, and You'll get it
[image]

You can then continue with @ir7 's answer

**Note : The Diagram is not upto the scale**

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $ABCD$ be the rectangle (length of $AB$ be $24$ and length of $BC$ be $10$) , and $MN$ be the crease segment, with $M$ on segment $AB$ and $N$ on segment $CD$, resulting from forcing   opposite corners $A$ and $C$ to overlap.

Consider right triangle $CMB$.

Denoting length of segment $MB$ by $x$ and noting that length of segment $CM$ is $24-x$, by Pythagoras theorem we get:

$$ (24-x)^2 = x^2 +10^2.$$

Once we have $x$, length of $MN$ is easy to obtain.